# Every length minimizing $\mathcal C^1$ curve is a geodesic.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ a manifold and $\gamma (t)$ for $t\in [a,b]$ a curve $\mathcal C^1$ the is minimizing the length. Then, if $p=\gamma (t_0)$ and $q=\gamma (t_1)$, then $\gamma $ is also minimizing the length of $p$ and $q$ for all $a\leq t_0<t_1\leq b$. In polar coordinates in $B(p,r)$, we have $$\gamma |_{[t_0,t_1]}=(r(t),\gamma ^1(t),...,\gamma ^{n-1}(t))$$
and

\begin{align*}
d(p,q)&=\ell(\Gamma)|_{[t_0,t_1]}\\
&=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\|\dot \gamma (t)\|\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\sqrt{\dot r(t)+g_{ij}(\gamma (t))\dot y^i\dot y^j}\mathrm d t\\
&\geq \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\sqrt{\dot r(t)^2}\\
&=r(t_1)-r(t_0)\\
&=d(p,q).
\end{align*}

We have equality if and only if $\dot y^i=0$ for all $i$, i.e. if $y^i=const$, which proves the claim.

**Question**

I don't understand the proof, why we have show that $\gamma $ is a geodesic ? To me, we only proved that $d(p,q)\geq d(p,q)$ (which is in fact obvious). Any way, any explanation is welcome.

Comment: Please review your posting and try to write meaningful sentences. It starts with the heading, which, to me, does not make any sense.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm sorry but what is not clear ? I'm sorry, but I'm not english, maybe I do some language mistakes.

Comment: I made some changes to your question, please check whether it reflects your intention.

Comment: @Thomas: It looks ok for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates $(r,\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n)$, the rays $t\mapsto (t,a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n)$ (where the $a_i$ are constant) are known to be geodesics, and the same applies to reparametrizations $t\mapsto (\phi(t),a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n)$ .

The sketch of proof you replicated shows that, in polar coordinates, the length minimizer is of this form.

Comment: So in my proof, we have that if $\dot y^i\neq 0$, then, $$d(p,q)=\ell(\gamma )>d(p,q),$$ and thus, we must have $\dot y^i=0$ ? Is it that ?

Comment: @user330587 yes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question why the proof shows that the curve is a geodesic:

Once we prove that $y^i$'s are constant, then $\gamma$ coincides with a radial curve, namely with $t \longrightarrow (t,y^1,...)$ which is by definition of polar coordinates a geodesic.

Therefore, we have shown that small segments (because we restricted ourselves to $p-q$ part) of the curve are geodesics. But this is true of any segment, hence proving that the whole curve is a geodesic.